# Using an Timer to switch a Boolean value?

Tags: swift, boolean, selector, nstimer

I'm relatively new to coding and I'm trying to switch a boolean value by with `Timer`. However, I keep getting an error. Here's my code:

```
var Display = true

var BoolTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ThirdViewController.SwitchBool), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func SwitchBool()
{
    if Display == true{
        Display = false
        print(Display)
    } else {
        Display = true
        print(Display)
    }
}
```

I get this error when the timer runs out:

```
[_SwiftValue SwitchBool]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000646ed0
2018-02-13 10:55:35.664486+1300 HC 1[12286:466779] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue SwitchBool]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000646ed0'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Can someone help me understand why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the current view controller `ThirdViewController`? By the way: please conform to the naming convention that function and variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Your timer should be created inside of some function, such as `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I would recommend you use the closure-based timer, rather than the selector based on. And the closure could just be `display = !display; print(display)`

Comment: @Alexander That won't fix the issue the OP is having, though; the `display` property will not be able to be accessed from the closure since `self` is not available yet.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I know, which I why I provided this comment as a comment, and not an answer. I intend for it to be considered alongside the answer, not in replacement of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run this code, what would you expect the output to be?

```
import Foundation

class C: NSObject {
    var foo = type(of: self)
}

print(C().foo)
```

You're expecting to see `C`, right? But instead you get:

```
(C) -> () -> C
```

The reason for this is that when you use `self` in a property's default value, `self` refers to a closure which is created as part of the initialization process, not to the object itself. The reason for this is that the property default values are computed before the object's `init` function has completed, and you can't use `self` before the object has completed initialization. So, Objective-C is trying to send the `SwitchBool` method to a closure, which of course doesn't support that method.

To fix this, just make the property `lazy`; this will cause the property to be initialized sometime after the object itself has been initialized, which will make it possible to use `self` and have it actually refer to your object, as you can see from the following test:

```
import Foundation

class C: NSObject {
    lazy var foo = type(of: self)
}

print(C().foo)
```

which outputs:

```
C
```

EDIT: If the object in question is a view controller, initializing the timer to `nil` and creating it in `viewDidLoad`, as suggested by @vacawama, is also a good approach to take. Basically you just need to make sure you create the timer at some point after the object has completed its initialization.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer, it is very clear now! thank you